# Remove "data-sheets-value" from tables, tr and td in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

For some reason, TinyMCE is allowing an invalid attribute from Google Sheets.

Here is an example:

```
<tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td data-sheets-hyperlink="link" data-sheets-formula="link">Foo</td>
    <td data-sheets-hyperlink="link" data-sheets-formula="link">Bar</td>
    <td data-sheets-hyperlink="link" data-sheets-formula="link">Foo</td>
    <td data-sheets-hyperlink="link" data-sheets-formula="link">Bar</td>
    <td data-sheets-hyperlink="link" data-sheets-formula="link">Foo</td>
</tr>
```

I already tried to set `data-sheets-hyperlink` and `data-sheets-formula` as invalid attributes using `valid_elements` and `invalid_elements`, but TinyMCE still allows it.

Any idea on how to remove these attributes as they are not useful and can be an issue for big tables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TinyMCE is not removing `data-*` attributes

Try this fiddle with [TinyMCE][1] configured to parse as full XHTML and fill it's source code with:

```
<a dir="" style="color: red;" href="https://google.com" data-v-test="">TEST</a>
<ul>
<li tabindex="2" dir>List element</li>
</ul>
```

Output is

```
<p><a href="https://google.com" style="color: red;" data-v-test="">TEST</a></p>
<ul>
<li>List element</li>
</ul>
```

Check this [answer][2].